# closure-compiler-js and grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

**Tl;dr:** I want to use npm instead of java when compiling my JS with closure compiler.

Hi all,

So apparently, closure compiler is getting rid of the dependency to Java and instead use JS (https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js).

My question to you guys and gals is if there is any way of using Grunt for this, or if I need to use Gulp as a build system? Currently they do not mention it on the link i pasted above, and I haven't seen anything about it elsewhere.

I am aware that the version that is dependent on Java can use grunt, but i would rather not to have to install Java (there are multiple developers using C#.NET 4.6 in this project, and I think they are all allergic to Java because they all are hissing when i mention it).

Comment: I added a comment to the thread that was referenced to in that page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure-compiler does not plan to remove the java version. The JS version is simply another option. It doesn't require java, but is also a bit slower on large code bases. It also doesn't expose nearly as many options currently.

You can use the java version via NPM - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler and it does have a grunt option.

There isn't a grunt option for the JS version because nobody has created one yet. The maintainers will most likely accept a pull request that adds grunt support if it is well written.

In the mean time, the java version still has a grunt option.

Comment: I am marking this answer as solution as it answers my question.
Thank you for the response!